# Which is the best way to take backup of all table data either merging one or separate in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, backup

In SQL Server 2005, I have a requirement to take backup the output table After Monthly Processing, the output table contains 50,000 rows. Which is the best way to take backup of the table for each month either taking backup as one table or monthly wise separate tables. Which method provides to save memory and best performance for managing data in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there would be any wrong answer here.. but it depends mostly on how this backup table will be used. What I would do:

Back everything up to the single table, but with another field named RunMonth (or something similar) that will indicate the month that those 50k records belong to. This would make querying the historical data much easier as opposed to having them in separate tables.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what about taking one table backup per year?

Comment: That would certainly work; you just need to keep in mind that if you ever wanted to retrieve say, 5 years worth of data, you'd need to do UNIONS across all those tables. But again, there really is no wrong answer here - just depends on what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a backup of the entire table is better not because it saves space but because it is much easier to handle.

But again, I would have multiple tables for each months rather handle the same with date/ date time field in a single table.

In my opinion, I would just backup the entire schema frequently so as to minimise any data lose.

Comment: Thanks for your reply